# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function Laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.3, jquery-select2, laravel-blade

I am using Select2 and seeing the error below. This is my file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('css/select2.min.css')}}">

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <select name="primaryLanguage" id="primaryLanguage">
                          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/jquery-1.10.2.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/select2.full.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("primaryLanguage").select2();
        });
    </script>
```

The error i keep getting:

```
home:7 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function(anonymous function) @ home:7fire @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3101self.fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3213jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3425completed @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3455
jquery-1.9.0.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
```

Comment: you jquery is not loaded

Comment: maybe 404 check the console

Comment: Post how you include jQuery and select2 plugin as it seems the plugin is not being loaded whilst jQuery is.

Comment: check the console see you have any 404

Comment: and make sure you are not loading jquery twice

Answer (score 1):

i just faced your own problem, i solved it like this: 
put these

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

in your main layout file (in my case app.blade.php)
then under those scripts put 
`@yield('scripts')`
Then in your blade file where you want to call the plugin, after the

```
@section('content') 
...
@endsection
@section('scripts')
 <!-- Here you call the select2 js plugin -->
@endsection
```

PS : you must put the css file & js file under public folder (public/css & public/js) 
And here i'm using Laravel Collective for the forms
I hope i helped

Answer (score 1):

just remove this code from you main layout

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: why do you suggest doing this as I've got `require(./bootstrap')` and `require('admin-lte')` in that. Why would removing it work?

Answer (score 0):

try modifying this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("#primaryLanguage").select2();
   });
</script>
```

In your code, you are refering to a tag having name `primaryLanguage`. But actually it is an `id`. Hence you are missing `#` to specify the `tag` with specific 'id'.

Comment: When I edited as you proposed now I'm now getting the error thus:```jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function TypeError: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/home:7:35)
    at j (http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).select2 is not a function```

Comment: Highly appreciate your support.

Comment: As @Araz mention in comment, Is your Js files are loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `primaryLanguage` you used as `id`, so now change a small code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#primaryLanguage").select2();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using Laravel mix, I think the error happened by calling the script js/app.js
lastly it should be called first, i did it and it was resolved

Comment: Explaining what resolved your issue could help other users understand what they have to do :)
You could also share your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).